# What does this c++ class declaration mean?

Tags: c++

I saw this piece of code in an article I am reading.

```
class EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API CUnmanagedTestClass
{
public:
    CUnmanagedTestClass();
    virtual ~CUnmanagedTestClass();
};
```

What does EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Lookup `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` on the web.

Comment: It looks like `EXAMPLEUNMANAGED_API` is a preprocessor macro. You should look to see what it is defined as.

Comment: I saw this in some code: `QNG_ASSERT_PTR_NE(join_cb, NULL);` - can someone tell me what `QNG_ASSERT_PTR_NE` does in C++? (This is a rhetorical question)

Comment: If you are using code that does that, you might want to look into the dangers of using C++ class interfaces across DLL boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for the purpose of exporting or importing the functions of a class into a DLL.

Read this article on MSDN for additional information:  [Using dllimport and dllexport in C++ Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx)

The common practice is to use conditional compilation in the headers of the class, so that the same header can be used for producing the DLL or consuming the DLL:

```
#ifdef EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_EXPORTS 
    #define EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else 
    #define EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif
```

In this example, the code or the buildscripts of your library would define symbol `EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_EXPORTS`.

Answer (score 1):

Such constructs are used in Windows to control whether the class is being used while building a DLL or it is being used to build a user of the DLL.

When building the DLL, `EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API` needs to expand to `__declspec(dllexport)`.

When buidling users of the DLL, `EXAMPLEUNMANAGEDDLL_API` needs to expand to `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Further information can be found at:

1. [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx)
2. [Importing into an Application Using __declspec(dllimport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fskxacy.aspx)