# dllexport static class methods

Tags: c++, static, dllexport

I am using Visual Studio and am working on some C++ code that works like this in class `A`:

```
class A
{
public:
    //......
    static void foo();
};
```

class `B` is exported:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) B
{
public:
    //...
    void bar()
    {
        A::foo();
    }
};
```

`A` and `B` are compiled to AB.dll (and AB.lib).
Now the main program:

```
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.bar();
    return 0;
}

When compiling the main program and linking it to AB.lib,
it complains about the A::foo() as unresolved external symbol
(in this case A::foo is a static function).
Do I need to somehow export A::foo() or could it be that 
I introduce errors somewhere?  Any help is appreciated.

Modified: 
1) Sorry for the type, it should be dllexport, not dllimport
2) in my actual project, the implementation is in .cpp files.  They are not inline functions.
Thanks.
```

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35048940/what-does-this-c-class-declaration-mean might be helpful.

Comment: Put the implementation of `B::bar` in the source file, don't export it. If `A` is only used in the source of `B` you shouldn't need to export it.

Comment: You give the linker two ways to resolve B::bar().  It can use the definition from the .h file or it can use the one in AB.lib.  That's a foregone conclusion, it will always like the one from the .h file since it is present in the .obj file.  Now it needs to resolve A::foo().  Fail whale, AB.lib does not have it.  You must remove the definition in the .h file and move it into the .cpp file so the compiler cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume code showed is in your .h header file, then when you header file says:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) B
{
public:
    //...
    void bar()
    {
        A::foo();
    }
};
```

First: you say B class is IMPORTED, it works for your main app, but not works for your dll.

Second: B::bar() IS NOT IMPORTED FROM dll, instead IS DIRECTLY IMPLEMENTED IN YOUR MAIN APP (compiler is readding directly in your header file, and it is not trying to import from dll)

Recomendations:

FIRST: redefine your header file like this:

```
class __declspec(dllimport) B
{
public:
    //...
    void bar();
};
```

And implement method B::bar in a cpp file in dll project

SECOND: remove class A from your header file (if you can)